# How to get the devicetoken in another class that is not the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, appdelegate, devicetoken

Good afternoon. I'm Brazilian so excuse me for any English errors!

I'm sending push notifications to my own device. I can get my deviceToken in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {  
    NSLog(@"Device Token Global : %@", deviceToken);   
}
```

But I have a class called `LoginViewController.m` where I perform a login and POST the `deviceToken` to a webservice (which inserts it into a mySQL table). How can I get this `deviceToken` as a string in my LoginViewController.m class?

Comment: What do you currently have in the way of the model component of your application, in model-view-controller terms?

Answer (score 9):

Convert the token to a string:

```
NSString *tokenString = [deviceToken description];
tokenString = [tokenString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]; 
tokenString = [tokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Store the token to `NSUserDefaults` using an application-specific key of your choosing:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tokenString forKey:@"MyAppSpecificGloballyUniqueString"];
```

Then, retrieve it elsewhere in your app:

```
NSString *tokenString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAppSpecificGloballyUniqueString"];
```

You don't **have** to use `NSUserDefaults`. You can use any sort of global state, singleton object, registry, or dependency injection to pass the value around. How you do that is up to you; this is merely an example.

Comment: Thanks for above code. Only the last line did not work for me. Instead of `stringforKey`, I used `objectforKey` and then it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: I was trying to resolve this problem for some days, till I found Your version, which is working perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a singleton class and create a device string (deviceString).

```
singletonObject.deviceString = [deviceToken description];
singletonObject.deviceString = [tokenString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]; 
singletonObject.deviceString = [tokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Now you can use the singletonObject.deviceString in any other class